# Dirac notation for English

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Dirac notation is very expressive: not only does it allow to write quantum states and operations more concisely, it can also be used to shorten written English words and phrases! Here are some examples:

[image: Dirac notation puzzle]

What is shown on the hidden photo?

Comment: My friend and I created this puzzle for a Christmas-themed mini-escape-room, in which you had to help Santa escape from a quantum lab. Enjoy!

Comment: Can you change image hosting, please? There are problems with accessing imgur.com in my country.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but i.stack.imgur.com is how Stack Exchange images *should* be hosted; converting the images would make the question less self-contained which is the opposite of what we would want.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The answer is

> Silver Tinsel

Because

> treating <Ψ| as "BRA" and |Ψ> as "KET" (their names from Dirac notation, as they form the begining and ending "BRAcKET")

We get

> coBRA basKET
>  BRAclet trinKET
>  celeBRAtion rocKET
>  viBRAnt marKET
>  BRAin locKET
>  zeBRA sKETch

Taking the

> letters from the numbered blanks from the pictures

Gives

> the Christmassy  SILVER TINSEL

Comment: "Shorten", as in rot13(ercynpr guerr yrggref jvgu guerr flzobyf?  Abg rknpgyl fubegre...)